# Multiply DataFrame rows with cartesian product between several columns containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find an effective / pythonic way to achieve the following:
 - for each row in df, generate the cartesian product between `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3`.
 - each tuple of the cartesian product would be a new row in a dataframe
 - for each rows, insert the other columns in the original dataframe (in my example that would be `Id` and `Grp`
I know that I can get the cartesian product with something like `list(itertools.product(a, b, c))`, but I have no idea how to do this in a dataframe environment.  I *could* do this in a for loop, but the production dataframe is likely to have over 100k rows, so I'm thinking efficiency first.

Python version used: 3.6+

Input dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,2],
                   'Grp': ['A','B'],
                   'Var1': [[11,12],[11,19]],
                   'Var2': [[0],[20,25]],
                   'Var3': [[34],[31,35,38]]
        })
```

Expected output (either `CartesianProduct` or `Var1, Var2, Var3` is fine, I don't need both):

```
   CartesianProduct Grp  Id  Var1  Var2  Var3
0       (11, 0, 34)   A   1    11     0    34
1       (12, 0, 34)   A   1    12     0    34
2      (11, 20, 31)   B   2    11    20    31
3      (11, 20, 35)   B   2    11    20    35
4      (11, 20, 38)   B   2    11    20    38
5      (11, 25, 31)   B   2    11    25    31
6      (11, 25, 35)   B   2    11    25    35
7      (11, 25, 38)   B   2    11    25    38
8      (19, 20, 31)   B   2    19    20    31
9      (19, 20, 35)   B   2    19    20    35
10     (19, 20, 38)   B   2    19    20    38
11     (19, 25, 31)   B   3    19    25    31
12     (19, 25, 35)   B   4    19    25    35
13     (19, 25, 38)   B   5    19    25    38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `itertools`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product, chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,2],
                   'Grp': ['A','B'],
                   'Var1': [[11,12],[11,19]],
                   'Var2': [[0],[20,25]],
                   'Var3': [[34],[31,35,38]]})

df['Cart'] = [list(product(*x)) for x in df[['Var1','Var2','Var3']].values.tolist()]

lens = list(map(len, df['Cart']))

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Grp': np.repeat(df['Grp'].values, lens),
                       'Id': np.repeat(df['Id'].values, lens),
                       'Cart': list(chain(*df['Cart'].values))})

df_out = df_out.join(pd.DataFrame(df_out['Cart'].tolist(),
                                  columns=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3']))

#             Cart Grp  Id  Var1  Var2  Var3
# 0    (11, 0, 34)   A   1    11     0    34
# 1    (12, 0, 34)   A   1    12     0    34
# 2   (11, 20, 31)   B   2    11    20    31
# 3   (11, 20, 35)   B   2    11    20    35
# 4   (11, 20, 38)   B   2    11    20    38
# 5   (11, 25, 31)   B   2    11    25    31
# 6   (11, 25, 35)   B   2    11    25    35
# 7   (11, 25, 38)   B   2    11    25    38
# 8   (19, 20, 31)   B   2    19    20    31
# 9   (19, 20, 35)   B   2    19    20    35
# 10  (19, 20, 38)   B   2    19    20    38
# 11  (19, 25, 31)   B   2    19    25    31
# 12  (19, 25, 35)   B   2    19    25    35
# 13  (19, 25, 38)   B   2    19    25    38
```

Comment: I think apply should be omit, `L = [list(product(*x)) for x in df[['Var1','Var2','Var3']].values.tolist()]` is better ;)

Comment: Looks great, can't test it right now on a larger dataframe but I will comeback with an update. One question: what does chain(*df['Cart'].values) do? I think i understand chain, but I'm baffled by the asterisk.